# Publish an uploaded photo using Facebook's Graph API

Tags: javascript, php, api, facebook, graph

I uploaded a photo form PC using Facebook's Graph API as mention in
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/resumable-upload-api

The response form the server was:

```
{"h": "2:::GCX1lgT2HE96k4EBABVmzuUrKpIEbugbAAAP:e:1614641018:953016678564535:106376874831684:ARY9xbszYdCO90XbXTE"}
```

which is a "file handle".

How can I publish the uploaded photo using that file handler?

Comment: Publish where ?

Comment: That page says you could use it to upload a user photo, or add to a page story. Towards the end then it says this though, _“Currently, the only supported use case is for creating a thumbnail when creating a page story.”_ - not sure which one is the truth. But in that last section it shows how you’d use the file handle to set the thumbnail for a page post, simply by supplying the file handle value as value for the `thumbnail` parameter.

Comment: Publish on a Facebook page or a user timeline @WizKid

Comment: Publish on a user timeline is not possible. How to publish things on pages you can read about on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing/